# How to downgrade Thrift version on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, version, thrift

I am using **Thrift version 0.14.0** on my Ubuntu (**20.04.2 LTS**).
However, I need to downgrade it to version **0.9.3** for working purposes.

I try to replace version 0.9.3, remove the current thrift version but it doesn't work.
Despite many ways to install the custom version, the current version is still 0.14.0 (thrift --version)

Can you give me the solution? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: How exactly did you install Thrift version 0.14.0, how exactly did you try to remove it or to downgrade it? Describe the "many ways to install the custom version. Maybe you have version 0.14.0 in `/usr/bin` and installed version 0.9.3 in `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: @Vinh Luu did you find solution to your issue? Can you post it here -thanks